# Publish apple store old sdk

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this but here it goes.

Currently I have an app built with `swift 2.1`, minimum supported SDK is 9.0 and I'm using `XCode 7.2.3`, my question is,  can I publish the app NOW(Tuesday, 4 October 2016), to the Apple Store without problems?

Best Regards.

Comment: yes you can publish it without any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, you can publish it to App Store. There is no constraint around Swift version for submitting to App Sore.